# Print Tuple from List in form each tuple values using String formatting

Tags: python

```
l=[(1,3,4),(9,8,10)..so on]
print ("x:{} y:{} z:{}".format(eachtuple) for eachtuple in l)

>>> output <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f17c5c950f0>
```

Thanks

Comment: Well `("x:{} y:{} z:{}".format(eachtuple) for eachtuple in l)` is a **generator**, not a **`for` loop**.

Answer (score 1):

use following code

```
for eachtuple in l:
    print "x:{} y:{} z:{}".format(*eachtuple)
```

Comment: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @KalpeshKadam just add *, need to unpack that.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways.

```
l = [(1,3,4), (9,8,10)]
for eachtuple in l:
    print("x:{} y:{} z:{}".format(*eachtuple))

for x, y, z in l:
    print("x:{} y:{} z:{}".format(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list comprehension, not a generator expression since it’s evaluated lazily, with a print inside, (don’t forget to unpack the tuple using *).

```
l=[(1,3,4),(9,8,10)]
[print ("x:{} y:{} z:{}".format(*eachtuple)) for eachtuple in l]
```